# Speed up scipy minimize

Tags: python, math, optimization, scipy, minimize

I have the minimum variance optimization problem in `scipy` with an additional constraint:

```py
def min_variance_scipy(initial_point: np.array, 
                       covariance_matrix: np.array):
    start = time.time()
    n = covariance_matrix.shape[0]
    
    objective_function = lambda w, c: 1000 * w.dot(c).dot(w)
    A = np.array([[1] * n])
    ub = [1]
    lb = [1]
    bounds = Bounds([0] * n, [1] * n)
    diversification_target = {
        'type': 'ineq',
        'fun': lambda weights: (2 / n) - np.sum(weights**2)
    }
    constraints = [LinearConstraint(A, lb, ub), diversification_target]
    
    solution = minimize(fun=objective_function,
                        x0=initial_point,
                        method='trust-constr',
                        bounds=bounds,
                        constraints=constraints,
                        args=(covariance_matrix,),
                        tol=1e-6,
                        jac=lambda x, c: 2000 * x.T.dot(c.T),
                        hess=lambda x, c: 2000 * c.T,
                        options={'gtol': 1e-6})
                        # options={'verbose': 3, 'finite_diff_rel_step': 1e-5,})
     
    return solution.x
```

If I run this optimizer with:

```
initial_point: np.array of shape == (600, ).
covariance_matrix: matrix of shape == (600, 600)
```

The execution time is +100 segs. I want to speed up this performance. I tested `cvxpy` but some constraints  are not DCP or DCCP if we use the DCCP optimizer. (I have more constraints to test).

I also changed the method parameter to `SLSQP` but the `diversification_target` constraint is not being fulfilled.

Comment: SciPy minimize can be pretty slow. I myself used it for optimizing a maximum likelihood function to find an ROI in an 256x256 image and it took ~45 secs per image. I'd suggest using `fmincon` in MATLAB (if you have it)

Comment: I believe this is a convex quadratically constraint problem. There are good solvers available for this (including high-performance commercial solvers). To model this I would suggest looking at CVXPY. It supports different solvers, so it easy to experiment and see how they perform.